# Result UNION MySql different in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

MYSQL

```
SELECT A.judul FROM tb_pengetahuan A UNION SELECT B.judul FROM tb_forum B
```

RESULT MYSQL
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD6no.jpg)

PHP

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT judul FROM tb_pengetahuan UNION SELECT judul FROM tb_forum");
$no=1;
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $judul = $data['judul'];
}
```

RESULT
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXCxr.jpg)

Why the results differ ?

I want the same results as in MySql, Can you help me ?

Comment: 1) be sure you are connecting to the same database.  2) why did you remove the table aliases in the php query?  i can't imagine how that plays into it, but it is still curious.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.